# What are the various ways to trigger form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a plugin that needs to "pre-process" an arbitrary form before it is submitted.

The catch is that this plugin will be used on forms over which I have no control and those who use it don't know how to code.

I'd prefer to support a number of different submission scenarios to maximize compatibility.

So, I'm trying to think of all of the various ways that a form submission can be triggered. Here's what I have so far:

1. Clicking on any `<input>` field annotated with `type='submit'` or `type='image'`.
2. Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> with the focus on an `<input>` field annotated with `type='submit'` or `type='image'`.
3. Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> with the focus on a `<button>` field that is not annotated with `type='reset'`.
4. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the focus on an `<input>` or `<select>` field that is not annotated with `type='reset'`.
5. Programmatically submitting the form using `form.submit()`.
6. AJAX submission triggered in any number of ways (fwiw, this scenario is quite complex and I'll likely have to settle for graceful degradation).

**What other possibilities have I missed?**

Comment: Some scenarios might be present in a spec, while others might be user-agent-specific. I'm primarily interested in common scenarios, but it would certainly be useful to know about user-agent-specific scenarios, too.

Comment: (For example, according to MDN, ["The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by default."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type). However, my brief testing indicates that a "blank" button does submit the form in Chrome.

Comment: in cases like (1) in the question, what would happen if the user clicks the submit button, but JS opens a popup or confirm dialog instead of submitting the form??

Comment: Pressing Space with the focus on a `<button>` with `type="button"` will not submit the form. I don't know what happens if you annotate a `<select>` with `type="reset"`. Probably nothing, but it won't affect form submission.

Comment: @moustafa Good question! For the purposes of this question, I think handling the scenario in #1 is pretty straightforward. However, with regard to UX, your implied point is a good one - that there might be some issues to consider. Handling all cases universally is ultimately impossible, so some concessions will likely need to be made.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Nice! According to my testing (Chrome, macOS), an "empty" `<button>` does submit the form, but you're right - `<button type="button">` (and `<input type="button"`) do not submit the form. This seems to also apply to clicking the buttons (not just pressing `Space`)

Answer (score 0):

Form submission trigger

Form Element: The form element that was clicked.
Form Classes: An array of the values found in the form's class attribute.
Form ID: The ID attribute of the form element.
Form Target: The target attribute of the form element.
Form URL: The href attribute value of the form element, if any.

Comment: This should be covered by #5 in the question, right? Thanks for your answer, btw!

Comment: There is no (valid) `href` attribute on a `form` element. There's an `action` attribute, but that's not a "submission trigger". In fact none of these are submission triggers, just attributes of a form.